# Android view pdf landscape in app without download from url

Tags: java, android, google-docs

I have a url of pdf file and I need view it (landscape) in app without download. I has try some library but them require download to read. I has try google doc but the pdf is showing with portrait. Please help me.

```
webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&portrait=false&url=" + url);
```

Comment: you cannot view a file without downloading it, As you cannot open a weppage content without opening it

Comment: Mention your activity screen orientation as landscape in manifest and try

Comment: @Mark Do, if u give the url like above simply it will download the file from respective site, if u want to view the content give it in html format. Thank you

Comment: @RafaelT sravs Varma thank for help me